# update column value using python script has no effect on table

Tags: python, mysql

I have added new column to the existing mysql table with default value as '0'.
Ia m trying to update those values to '1' using python script but it does not have any effect on the table.

on the log

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_1`.`violations` WHERE 0=1
```

this is my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
from mydb import cursor
from twisted.enterprise import util as dbutil
from MySQLdb import escape_string



sql ="UPDATE `customer_1`.`violations` SET `flag`='1' WHERE `flag`='0' ";

print sql
cursor.execute(sql)
```

It works when I run  the same statment on mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the quotes from 0

Comment: Tried that still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to do commit after execute the statement?

```
cursor.commit()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit' -error